# MTProto Telegram API PEER_ID_INVALID for User B, but not A

Tags: typescript, telegram, telegram-api, mtproto

I have the following problem:

When successfully connected to **User A**, i can send messages to another **User X** like that:

```
  await this.api.call('messages.sendMessage', {
    peer: {
      _: 'inputPeerUser',
      user_id: *****123*****,               // user_id of User X
      access_hash: "*****111******"         // access_hash of User X
    },
    message: current.message + ' ' + current.emoji,
    random_id: current.user.userId + Math.floor(Math.random())
  });
```

Everything works as expected. Now I also have **User B**, which also likes to send messages to **User X**.

But, if I use the standard authentication flow like:

1. call sendCode()
2. received the SMS Code, pass it to the MTPROTO Object
3. keep the current MTPROTO Object and authenticate, it works for **both** Accounts
4. Trying to fetch channels from each user works **as well**

If i try to send a message to **User X** from **User B** i receive:

```
{
  _: 'mt_rpc_error',
  error_code: 400,
  error_message: 'PEER_ID_INVALID'
}
```

Are there any restrictions on who can write to whom?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Did you found a Solution?

Comment: no solution from my side.